# Centrar div al ocultar otro div

Tags: html, div, bootstrap

Tengo en 1 row 2 columnas, una es un menu arbol del lado izquierdo y un pdf del lado derecho.

menu izquierdo

```
<div id=myDIV>
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row  " > 
          <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-3 col-lg-3 sidenav"
CONTENIDO
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Y el div de la derecha:

```
  <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-6 col-lg-9" align="center">
  <embed src="aa.pdf" width="700px" height="500px" type="application/pdf">
  es un PDF DE PRUEBA
   </div>
```

Mediante jquery hice el boton que dice CLICK ME para que oculte el menu izquierdo y solo quede el PDF

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

$('#todoen1').click(function(){    /*#todoen1 es el BOTON*/
    $('#myDIV').fadeToggle('slow');  /*myDIV 
});

});
```

[image: Imagen derecha asi queda]
El detalle está en que al ocultar el div izquierdo, el div derecho se mueve muy a la izquierda, NO queda centrado en medio de la pagina y es lo que estoy queriendo hacer.
Hay alguna manera de que al ocultar el DIV izquierdo el DIV derecho quede centrado? Justo en medio de la pagina

Utilizo bootstrap

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es tener un tercer div que mantenga el aspecto pero sea totalmente invisible.

Comment: Si sirvió esa parte, hice otro DIV con la meddia correcta pero con un display none, y lo mostré y oculté con jquery

Comment: Te pongo la respuesta para que la votes Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es tener un tercer div que mantenga el aspecto pero sea totalmente invisible.

Comment: Un ejemplo ayudaría a mejorar la calidad de tu aporte

Answer (score 0):

Si sirvió esa parte que comentó Miguel Clavijo, hice otro DIV con la meddia correcta pero con un display none, y lo mostré y oculté con jquery – Jose Tapia ahora mismo   Editar   Eliminar